# How to Properly Share as Image Service?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, imagery, aerial-photography, image-service

I have 5 historical aerial sets for my county each consisting of several hundred SID files. Previous employees have created Image Catalogs for each. Now I want to turn these into services I can share with ArcGIS for Server 10.1. Running the mosaic tool is taking forever, I started at 830am and as of 4pm it is only through 30 of 508 files. There has to be an easier way?

Is there a workflow or a way that will be quicker?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're running the Mosaic tool rather than making a Mosaic Dataset (yes, the naming can be confusing).  The Mosaic tool creates a new output raster and takes a long time etc.  A Mosaic Dataset references the images in the location they're already stored and can perform raster operations on the fly.